# PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Tengo este error y no envia datos de mi formulario a mi base de datos he seguido un tutorial al pie de la letra he intentado analizar linea por linea de codigo pero no funciona el envio de datos de mi formulario y veo que tengo este errror.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo PHP

```
<?php
    include_once 'conexion.php';
    
    $conexion = new Connection();
    $db = $conexion->open();
    //Se obtiene de la etiqueta name del formulario
    $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
    $apellido=$_POST['apellido'];

    
    $insert= "INSERT INTO datos (nombre, apellido) VALUES (?,?)";
    $statement=$db->prepare($insert);
   
    $statement->bindParam(1, $nombre, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $statement->bindParam(2, $apellido, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $statement->execute();

    $conexion->close();

?>
```

Este es el formulario HTML que estoy usando para practicar.

```
<form id="enviarD" method="POST" action="">
        <input type="text" name="nombre" value="Nombre"></input>
        <input type="text" name="apellido" value="Apellido"></input>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Enviar</button>
    </form>
```

Y estoy usando ajax para el envio de datos

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    enviardatos();
});
function enviardatos() {
    $("#enviarD").on("submit" , function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var datos=$(this).serialize()
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "add.php",
            data:datos,
            success: function () {
                alert("Success!");
            },
            error:function () {
                alert("Error!");
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Prueba cambiando `var datos=$(this).serialize()` por `var datos=$("#enviarD").serialize()` y dinos si se arregla

Comment: Ya lo intente y no funciona.

Comment: Pues depura el PHP poniendo esta linea `file_put_contents('depuracion.txt', print_r($_POST, true));` al principio del script y ejecuta el formulario una vez, y luego te vas a la carpeta/directorio donde esta el script y abres el archivo recien creado `depuracion.txt` y miras que pone.  Si te sale un array vacio entonces algo tienes mal en el ajax, sino comprueba las claves recibidas y busca el error a partir de ahi.

Answer (score 1):

En primer lugar, tienes mal organizado el código. Lo correcto sería llamar la petición Ajax cuando el botón `Enviar` sea presionado, para ello basta con tener a `$("#enviarD").on("submit" , function (e) {` dentro del document ready (el cual por cierto es obsoleto desde jQuery 3).

Por otra parte, en tu programación de PHP estás prácticando la programación que yo llamo *ingenua* o *programación optimista*: consiste en escribir código pensando que todo es color de rosa. No controlas todo aquello que puede fallar, y no eres coherente con la realidad de los datos. Si tienes restricciones NOT NULL para tus valores, deberías verificar que los mismos no son nulos.

Así debería funcionar:

```
/*document.ready es obsoleto desde jQuery 3*/
$(function() {
    $("#enviarD").on("submit" , function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var datos=$(this).serialize();
        console.log(datos);

        $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "add.php",
                 data:datos,
                 success: function () 
                 {
                      alert("Success!");
                 },
                 error:function () 
                 {
                      alert("Error!");
                 }
        });
    });
});
```

---

```
<?php
    
    /*Debes verificar que los datos no son nulos*/
    $nombre=$_POST['nombre'] ?? null;
    $apellido=$_POST['apellido'] ?? null;
    
    if ($nombre && $apellido) {
        include_once 'conexion.php';          
        $conexion = new Connection();
        /*Debes verificar que la conexión no es nula*/
        if ($db = $conexion->open()) {
            $insert= "INSERT INTO datos (nombre, apellido) VALUES (?,?)";
            $stmt=$db->prepare($insert);
            $stmt->bindParam(1, $nombre, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(2, $apellido, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            /*
                Debes controlar OTROS posibles errores
                como registro duplicado
            */
            if ($stmt->execute()) {
                $msg=sprintf("Filas insertadas: %d",$stmt->rowCount());
            } else {
                $msg="Error insertando";
            }
        } else {
            $msg="No hay conexión";
        }
    } else {
        $msg="No se recibieron datos en el POST";
    }
    echo $msg;
    
?>
```

Tu código PHP es ahora más largo, pero no es un programa ingenuo. Un programa no se puede considerar acabado si no implementa de forma sólida el manejo de errores.